# doctype causing css not to load

Tags: html, css, doctype

Creating a html5 webpage that contains the html5 doctype it doesn't load the css. But when I remove the doctype it does load the css. The page contains the standard html5 doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

My stylesheet is linked correctly

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and my stylesheet doesn't contain any errors

I am creating the webpage in Brackets and the css does load with the doctype when using live preview but not when manually loading the page through webserver.

Comment: I would say  check the specs of your webserver. What do you see in the console log window of your browser if you load your website via this webserver?

Comment: Show a screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` shouldn't be causing this. The problem must be somewhere else. What does the console show? Does the browser even try to load the CSS? In Chrome for example you can see this in the Network tab of the Developer tools.

Comment: That console says 
    "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/javascript/css/styles.css"."

Comment: I only have one html page and folder containing the css at the moment

Answer (score 5):

The use of a Doctype is not going to prevent the browser from loading the CSS.

It will, however, switch the browser to use [Standards Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) in which it will stop emulating bugs in older browsers and try to more closely follow the specification.

This will frequently cause parts of the CSS which contain errors (such as lengths which are missing units) to be ignored (as required by the specification).

You may need to fix your CSS. A [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) will help you identify the faults with it.

Another possibility is that the server is claiming that the CSS is something else. Check the Net tab in your developer tools and ensure that the CSS is sent with a `Content-Type: text/css` header. It might be ignored if the server claims it is plain text or HTML.

---

Update:

> That console says Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

You need to fix the server so it provides the correct content type for the stylesheet. It should be `text/css` not `text/html`.

Comment: Do you how I could fix this. I am running the latest version of Apache. I have tried adding the mime type for css but that didn't work